# Groupby and aggregate using lambda functions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to groupby-aggregate a dataframe  using lambda functions that are being created programatically. This so I can simulate a one-hot encoder of the categories present in a column.

Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[10, 'A'], [10, 'B'], [20, 'A'],[30,'B']]),
                   columns=['ID', 'category'])

ID category
10 A
10 B
20 A
30 B
```

Expected result:

```
ID A B
10 1 1
20 1 0
30 0 1
```

What I am trying:

```
one_hot_columns = ['A','B']
lambdas = [lambda x: 1 if x.eq(column).any() else 0 for column in one_hot_columns]
df_g = df.groupby('ID').category.agg(lambdas)
```

Result:

```
ID A B
10 1 1
20 0 0
30 1 1
```

But the above is not quite the expected result. Not sure what I am doing wrong.
I know I could do this with get_dummies, but using lambdas is more convenient for automation. Also, I can ensure the order of the output columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(df.ID, df['category']).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
category  ID  A  B
0         10  1  1
1         20  1  0
2         30  0  1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with [`Groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
In [4331]: res = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['category']).groupby('ID', as_index=False).sum()

In [4332]: res
Out[4332]: 
   ID  category_A  category_B
0  10           1           1
1  20           1           0
2  30           0           1
```

OR, use `pd.concat` with `pd.get_dummies`:

```
In [4329]: res = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df.category)], axis=1).groupby('ID', as_index=False).sum()

In [4330]: res
Out[4330]: 
   ID  A  B
0  10  1  1
1  20  1  0
2  30  0  1
```